# Override IHttpModule SetHeaders in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have an image processing module that I register in web.config.  The module is an IHttpModule.  The module adds custom HTTP headers to the response.  Is it possible to suppress these headers in web.config? My attempt to do so failed - do IHttpModule override this web.config configuration?

```
 <httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <remove name="TheModuleeader" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to change/edit response headers with outbound rules. For example, this code is removing `Server` and `ETag` header:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <outboundRules>
        <rule name="Remove RESPONSE_Server" >
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Server" pattern=".+" />
          <action type="Rewrite" value="" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Remove RESPONSE_Server ETag">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_ETag" pattern=".+" />
          <action type="Rewrite" value="" />
         </rule>
      </outboundRules>      
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

You can apply similar rules to your unnecessary headers

Comment: Thanks Victor, you are correct in that this allows you to change/edit the header value.  However, I am trying to remove the header completely.

Comment: If you will rewrite it as empty it will remove it. Please try my rules above

Comment: I tried your suggestion.  Unfortunately the header is not removed.  The header is still returned but with an empty string value.